# replacing link with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a site that allows users to submit videos and attribute a source, sometimes they'll link with http:// and sometimes with just www. proceeding the links.

For various reasons I needed to prepend http:// on every link to ensure the URL resolved properly so I ran a simply bit of jquery to check the link when the page loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.status-contain a.source-container').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('http://http//', 'http://');

    });
});
```

This became a problem when people submitted links that where `https://` because the appended URL would become `http://https://` with jquery not recognising what to change.

Should I be creating some sort of if/ function to check if the URL is http or https then running a replace on that?

Simple problem but I'm a little stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this also,

```
 this.href = this.href.replace('http://https//', 'https://');
```

your code becomes,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('.status-contain a.source-container').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace('http://http//', 'http://');
    this.href = this.href.replace('http://https//', 'https://');

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check if `https` is present in `href` then replace it accordingly like below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.status-contain a.source-container').each(function(){
        var hrefVal = this.href;
        if(hrefVal.indexOf("https://")!=-1)
        {
          this.href = this.href.replace('http://https://', 'https://');
        }
        else
        {
          this.href = this.href.replace('http://http//', 'http://');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod) to add a custom url method validation. The custom validator can be something like this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_url", function(val, elem) {
// if no url, don't do anything
if (val.length == 0) { return true; }

// if user has not entered http:// https:// or ftp:// assume they mean http://
if(!/^(https?|ftp):///i.test(val)) {
    val = 'http://'+val; // set both the value
    $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
}
// now check if valid url
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url
// contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/iri/
return /^(https?|ftp)://(((([a-z]|d|-|.|_|~|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])|(%[da-f]{2})|[!$&amp;'()*+,;=]|:)*@)?(((d|[1-9]d|1dd|2[0-4]d|25[0-5]).(d|[1-9]d|1dd|2[0-4]d|25[0-5]).(d|[1-9]d|1dd|2[0-4]d|25[0-5]).(d|[1-9]d|1dd|2[0-4]d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|d|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])|(([a-z]|d|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])([a-z]|d|-|.|_|~|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])*([a-z]|d|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF]))).)+(([a-z]|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])([a-z]|d|-|.|_|~|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])*([a-z]|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF]))).?)(:d*)?)(/((([a-z]|d|-|.|_|~|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])|(%[da-f]{2})|[!$&amp;'()*+,;=]|:|@)+(/(([a-z]|d|-|.|_|~|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])|(%[da-f]{2})|[!$&amp;'()*+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(?((([a-z]|d|-|.|_|~|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])|(%[da-f]{2})|[!$&amp;'()*+,;=]|:|@)|[uE000-uF8FF]|/|?)*)?(#((([a-z]|d|-|.|_|~|[u00A0-uD7FFuF900-uFDCFuFDF0-uFFEF])|(%[da-f]{2})|[!$&amp;'()*+,;=]|:|@)|/|?)*)?$/i.test(val);
```

});